# How to make a new "Personal.xlsb" using VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm trying to make a new Excel file, "Personal.xlsb", using VSTO.

I've tried to make a new workbook - regular one, with code below;

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add();
```

Yes, it works well. But, as you know well, it cannot be a Personal.xlsb. So, what do I have to do  ?  Using VSTO ?

Let's say, I have nothing in the folder
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas?view=vsto-2017) method which saves the workbook in a different file or format. The [XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat?view=excel-pia) enum contains all the supported file formats.

Comment: Wow, Thanks. That sounds promising. I'll check it out.

Comment: Quite strange. In case of ordinary naming, it doesn't have any problem. Just like "thanksEAsta.xlsb". But, when you use "Personal.xlsb", you got nothing at all - should be error, silent silent and silent error. So.. afterwards, I could change the name from "thanksEAsta" to "Personal" then it looks like works well as an ExcelPersonal file. This is qood result, at the moment. THANKs Lot,  E Astafiev  !!!!